# Test upload complete to FTP server

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I'm trying to do an application that warns me when a user finishes uploading a file to my FTP server.
What I want is: when a user completes its transfer to my FTP server, I want that my application warn me.

How can I do that? In C#.NET…

Thanks. Best regards.

Comment: In what form you want the warning? MessageBox, Email ....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not have a small application that utilises the file watcher classes in .Net and when a file is created on the ftp location, send a email to yourself(or take any action you do require)?

See here for details:
[File Watcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)

This question may be of use as well 
[C# FileSystemWatcher And FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239616/c-filesystemwatcher-and-ftp)

Comment: The file is created when the transfer begin and not when the transfer completes. I want that my application warns me when the trasnfer is complete. And not when the file is created.

Comment: @arpf - the documentation says it can notify on changes too. Won't the file handle be closed when the upload is complete, and a change event be sent?

Answer (score 1):

Use [**FileSystemWatcher**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)

Similar [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/0ae97a91-ec92-481e-af87-b52836b1eff7).